# Show units sold as word on WooCommerce Archive and Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to understand how to show single and multiple values for my count.

Basically like this:

- "Bought by **one** customer so far" opposite "Bought by **1** customer so far"
- "Bought by **five** customer**s** so far" opposite "Bought by **5** customer**s** so far"

How can I convert the total sales number to a word/string?

**This is the code I am working with:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_sold_count', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'product_sold_count', 11 );
function product_sold_count() {
    global $product;
    $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'total_sales', true );
    if ($units_sold) echo '<span class="bought-by-customers">' . sprintf( __( 'Bought by %s customers so far', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</span>';
}
```

Which works, but not the way I prefer it. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question you can use the PHP [NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php),

You can also use [WC_Product::get_total_sales()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_total_sales/) versus `get_post_meta()`

So you get:

```php
function product_sold_count() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Get total sales
        $units_sold = $product->get_total_sales();
        
        if ( $units_sold >= 1 ) {
            // https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php
            $fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'en', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT );
            
            // Singular are plural
            $units_sold == 1 ? $s_p = '' : $s_p = 's';
        
            // Output
            echo '<span class="bought-by-customers">' . sprintf( __( 'Bought by %s customer%s so far', 'woocommerce' ), $fmt->format( $units_sold ), $s_p ) . '</span>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_sold_count', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'product_sold_count', 11 );
```

---

Result:

- Bought by thirty-one customer**s** so far
- Bought by one customer so far